# Where do I put substr?

Tags: php

I have this code that I need to add `substr` to, to limit the description output to 100 characters:

```
description=<?=nl2br(strip_tags($v['listing_description']));?>
```

Where and how do I add `substr` to this line?

I have tried a few different methods, with no success.

Comment: Could you post your attempts so we know what not to suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `substr` goes between `nl2br` and `strip_tags`:

```
description=<?=nl2br(substr(strip_tags($v['listing_description']), 0, 100));?>
```

The reason for this is because you *first* want to `strip_tags` (the inner-most parentheses), *then* `substr` to 100 characters, *then* convert new-lines to `<br>`s.